# How to add drop down box with information in a table cell using html

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, accordion, squarespace

I don't know anything about coding and have been tasked to work on a Squarespace site and I've been teaching myself using tutorials. I need to make a unique table. Similar to the table found here: https://www.idtech.com/register/#/reg-flow/avail-charts-filters?lid=78

I'd like to have a feature where when you click a table cell then a drop down box will appear with information written within. I also want the cell to collapse if you click on a different cell.

Is there any way you can make a sample for me? I tried manipulating "input=checkbox" but that failed and isn't compatible with the square space site. I tried accordion but that doesn't work for just particular cells.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this article to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can achieve that with only html,, you must use css or js.